# Using cordova video plugin for ios and Android

Tags: android, ios, cordova

I want to play videos in my app using the Cordova plugin, which is available for both the iOS and Android platforms. I am aware of the HTML5 video tag but wish to use plugins. I have tried [this plugin](https://github.com/nchutchind/Streaming-Media-Cordova-Plugin) and have successfully used it. However, it only plays videos from a web URL, and I wish to play videos from my local file system.

Can anyone tell me how to do this?